# Update a Record in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I'm having the following query while updating a particular record.

I've a user Column Family CF as follow:-

```
class User(Model):
    user_id = UUID(default=uuid.uuid4,primary_key= True)
    date = DateTime(primary_key=True,default=datetime.now())
    model = Text()
    gender = Text()
    imei = Text()
```

Now I want to filter users by `gender, model and imei`. So I made 3 models as follow. Note I could have defined `model, gender and imei` as **secondary indexes**, but secondary indexing has exponentially lower performance than normal querying, as there's nothing clever about it to back performance. Anything above a thousand records will seriously impair performance, hence I made 3 separate CF.

```
class UserByGender(Model):
    gender = Text(primary_key=True)
    date = DateTime(primary_key=True,default=datetime.now())
    user_id = UUID(index=True)


class UserByModel(Model):
    model = Text(primary_key=True)
    date = DateTime(primary_key=True,default=datetime.now())
    user_id = UUID(index=True)


class UserByImei(Model):
    imei1 = Text(primary_key=True)
    date = DateTime(primary_key=True,default=datetime.now())
    user_id = UUID(index=True)
```

I'm able to query and filter the total users by `gender, model and imei`. But the problem arises when I need to either **update/delete** a particular record.

While updating imei of a particular user, given the user_id,I do the following

```
imei_user_list = UserByImei.objects.get(user_id = 'some_user_id').update(imei='updated value')  
#Note: over here I'm again filtering by a secondary index. Is it worth?
```

I know the PK cannot be updated. Hence I thought of a solution, that I'll delete it first and then re-write the record, but deletes in cassandra rely on Tombstones to support the eventual consistency model.

How do I perform update operations on such model? Or how can I re-design my CF such that I'm able to update a record AND read the records(based on my different filters) as well ?

Comment: Could you show your tables model (using `describe tables` in cqlsh for instance)?

Comment: @GQuintana- I've updated my question(edited some text). Please go through it once again. Regards

Answer (score 0):

The (python?) ORM you're using is great, but it obfuscates the underlying schema. Cassandra 'primary keys' have 2 components - partition keys and clustering keys. Your class mapping does not make it clear what the underlying schema actually entails.

Consider drawing out the underlying CQL schema, and then looking at how each query (INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE) will apply to each table. If it doesn't work, re-design the table.

Comment: I'm majorly concerned with updating a PK, ie if I've a `User` CF and having columns such as `city`, `phoneno` etc. Lets suppose, I need to filter by `city` , hence I made another CF `UserByCity`. Querying this CF will generate fast results. But if a user updates his `city`, how will I update the `UserByCity` model ? Since update operations are not allowed on PK, how will I update user's city?

Comment: I've updated my question(edited some text). Please go through it once again. Thanks